# How to echo an array only if it has values in php?

Tags: php

I run a foreach loop, where some of the loops contain nothing into the following variables, they are empty.

However, the "hi world" is echoed always.

How can I show the "hello world" only if at least one of the `$row['utm_source'],$row['utm_medium'],$row['utm_campaign']` has a value?

```
$arr = array($row['utm_source'],$row['utm_medium'],$row['utm_campaign']);

if (!empty($arr)) {
    echo "hi world";
}
```

Comment: Where is your `foreach` loop ?

Answer (score 2):

You an do it using [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) and [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) :-

```
$arr = array($row['utm_source'],$row['utm_medium'],$row['utm_campaign']);

if (count(array_filter($arr))>0) {
  echo "hi world";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods:

**1. implode + trim**

implode joins the array items if they are strings together with the provided delimiter.

```
if( trim(implode("", $arr)) !== ""){
    echo "hi world";
}
```

**2. array_filter**

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) returns the items which returns true to the provided callback function.

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($d) { return trim($d) !== ""; });

if(count($arr)){
   echo "hi world";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough way you can do it

```
<?php
$row = array();
$row['utm_source'] = null;
$row['utm_medium'] = null;
$row['utm_campaign'] = 1;
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($key)){
        echo 'Hello';
        break;
    }
}
```

Here's the [eval link](https://eval.in/897609)

Also you can check it by

```
if (!empty($row['utm_source'])) {...}
```